# How to keep DbContext and entities internal while injecting into services?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an ASP Core MVC application. Within my solution I have Web project (MVC) and a Core project (BLL/DAL).

I thought it would be a good idea to keep my persistence models and DbContext inside Core project as internal, since Web project should never need the persistence models or need to access context directly, it will get all it needs from services.

Core project has an IServiceCollection extension method which allows me to add the DbContext from service layer to the service container in MVC project without MVC needing direct access to it.

The issue comes when I need to use the DbContext inside my service classes in Core project. The service classes must be public for the view layer to access them, but I cannot inject DbContext into them via the constructor because it is internal.

If I want to make the DbContext public so it can be injected, I must also make all of my persistence models public since they are declared with DbSets in the context.

Do I really need to make all of my persistence models public or is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: You can give the context an interface like any other class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make `Entity` public, otherwise, you will not be able to access them in Service Layer. We should reference `Entity` from Data Access Layer instead of accessing `ViewModel` from Service Layer in Data Access Layer. And then, you could make `DbContext` public to be able accessed from Service Layer.

If you want to avoid accessing `DbContext` directly from Service Layer, you could consider implementing public `Repository` which will inject `DbContext` to handle CURD operations.